# Why is “être” used in “Son estomac s'est mis à gronder.”

Tags: grammaire, participe-passé, verbes-pronominaux, passé-composé, auxiliaires

If I understand correctly, the sentence means "His stomach started to rumble/growl". I just don't understand which tense is it? If "se mettre a faire + infinitive" means to "begin doing something" (correct me if I'm wrong) and we want to say "someone began/started to do something" shouldn't it be in *passé composé* and hence "se **a** (s'a?) mis à gronder"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pronominal verbs like *se mettre* always use *être* as an auxiliary to form compound tenses.

> Ils se sont envolés pour Rome.

It's also the case for normal verbs accidentally used reflexively.

> Il a frappé son voisin.
>   Il s'est frappé sur la tête.

But beware of the agreement of the past participle in some reflexive uses of the verbs. Even though the auxiliary is *être* in appearance, the agreement is still done with a potential direct object, which may in some cases be different from the subject.

- *Elles se sont offert **des cadeaux**.* (the direct object appears after the verb)
- ***Les cadeaux*** qu'elles se sont offert**s**. (the direct object appears before the verb)
- *Ils se sont téléphoné.* (no direct object)
- *Ils **se** sont entendu**s**.* (the direct object is identical to the subject)

Comment: Wow that was extremely useful to me , thank you very much

Comment: I can't see the difference between the last 2 examples, could you explicit it a bit more ?

Comment: @Random On téléphone *à* quelqu'un, mais on entend quelqu'un.